# Хранение прогресса

Tags: mysql

Каким образом можно реализовать хранение в БД пройденные пользователем тесты?

Comment: А можете описать подробнее структуру существующей базы данных?

Comment: cheops она на уровне примитива, поэтому нечего показать. хотел теоритическое узнать решение.

Comment: А тестов много? Они идут в каком-то порядке? Просто хотелось бы больше подробностей об задаче.

Comment: @cheops да тестов немного, тем более они без какого-то деления по типам, сложности. ты про упорядочивание? хотелось бы по дате, но думаю, если записывать время и дату прохождения, то не будет проблемы.

Comment: @cheops прилетела мысль в голову, если хранить записи о пройденных тестах с айдишником юзера и временем прохождения  таблице, а потом просто тупо выборку сделать для конкретного пользователя сделать - это корректное решение? или костыль

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

- **Tests**: *test_id*, *test_name*, (другие параметры теста)...;
- **People**: *human_id*, *human_name*, (другие параметры человека)...;
- **People_Tests**: *test_id*, *p_id*, *result* (количество баллов или пройден/не пройден).

Таблица **Tests** хранит данные о всех тестах, которые есть.
Таблица **People** хранит зарегистрированных пользователей (людей, имеющих отношение к этому тестированию).
Таблица **People_Tests** хранит следующие данные: "Какой тест (*test_id*), был написан каким человеком (*human_id*) и успешно ли (*result*)".